# Number of strings counter, but stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: java

```
public class PersonName {
    public static int NumberNames(String wholename)
    {    // store the name passed in to the method
        String testname = wholename;
         // initialize number of names found
        int numnames = 0;
         // on each iteration remove one name
        while (testname.length() > wholename.length())
        {   // take the "white space" from the beginning and end
           testname = testname.trim();
           // determine the position of the first blank
           // .. end of the first word
           int posBlank = testname.indexOf(' ');           
           // cut off word
           testname=testname.substring(posBlank + 1, testname.length());
           System.out.println(numnames);
           System.out.println(testname);
           numnames++;        
        }    
        return numnames;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        PersonName One= new PersonName();

        System.out.println(One.NumberNames("Bobby"));
        System.out.println(One.NumberNames("Bobby Smith"));
        System.out.println(One.NumberNames("Bobby L. Smith"));
        System.out.println(One.NumberNames("  Bobby  Paul Smith Jr.  "));
    }
}
```

The code is supposed to take the strings given and output a result saying how many strings there are. I have this much so far, but the loop is stuck somewhere in the "PersonName" method. Anyone know why it's stuck?

Comment: This condition will never be true `while (testname.length()>wholename.length())` the `testname` and `wholename` will always be equal in length at the start because of the assignment.  Im not sure how its even starting the loop?

Comment: As always in situations like this, the debugger is your friend.

Comment: Please tell me this is homework and you're not allowed to use String.split()

Comment: This isn't really a problem that can be duplicated and it's more of a "debug my code" question.

Comment: PersonName is not a method, it is a class.  Try using split() on a space character and get the length of the result.  I don't see a "stuck" condition, I see the loop is never entered.  you set testname to wholename, so testname.length will never be greater than wholename.length, loop will not enter.

Comment: Sorry, there's a mistype there. It should be  while (testname.length()>0

Comment: Variables and methods should begin with lower case letters. You should not call a static method through an instance, even though the language allows it. As written, the while loop will never execute, but with the change mentioned in your comment, the while loop will never cut down `testname` at all if it doesn't contain a space, which it doesn't in your very first call, with `"Bobby"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int NumberNames(String t){
    if(t == null || t.length() == 0) return 0;

    return t.trim().split("\\s+").length;
}
```

Isn't this a lot easier?

EDIT:

If you want to use your actual code (just modified a bit):

```
public class PersonName
{
    public static int NumberNames(String wholename)
    {   
        // store the name passed in to the method
        // and replace multiple whitespaces for a single space
        // and take the "white space" from the beginning and end
        String testname = wholename.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
        int testnameLength = testname.length();
        // initialize number of names found
        int numnames = 0;
        // on each iteration remove one name
        while (testnameLength > 0)
        {   
           // determine the position of the first blank
           // .. end of the first word
           int posBlank = testname.indexOf(' ');
           // if we reached the last word, break the while-loop
           if(posBlank == -1)
           {
               numnames++;
               break;
           }
           // cut off word
           testname = testname.substring(posBlank + 1, testnameLength);
           testnameLength = testname.length();
           //System.out.println(numnames);
           //System.out.println(testname);
           numnames++;       
        }    
        return numnames;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        PersonName One= new PersonName();

        System.out.println(One.NumberNames("Bobby"));
        System.out.println(One.NumberNames("Bobby Smith"));
        System.out.println(One.NumberNames("Bobby L. Smith"));
        System.out.println(One.NumberNames("  Bobby  Paul Smith Jr.  "));
    }
}
```

I also made two ideones:

- [First code's ideone](http://ideone.com/38b3Ds)
- [Second code's ideone](http://ideone.com/k8Dhvr)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your loop condition:

```
while (testname.length() > 0) // this will always be true and is causing your infinite loop
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here but this is why your program is "stuck".

Answer (score 0):

while (testname.length()>wholename.length())

Your while loop will be true as long as the number of chars in testname is higher than the number of chars in wholename. This is never true since you make them equal to each other right before the loop. There are something here you should change, but I don't know what, since I'm not sure what kind of result you want :)

Answer (score 0):

The while loop should be like this :

```
while (testname.length()>numnames)
```

Comment: This is incorrect. For example, we have the following sentence "This is test A". First iteration (nothing removed yet): `14 > 0`; second iteration ("This " is removed from base): `9 > 1`; third iteration ("This is " is removed from base): `6 > 2`; fourth iteration ("This is test " is removed from base): `1 > 3 == false', giving the answer 3 and doing nothing with the "A" while it should be 4. I don't know why this answer was upvoted, because it doesn't make any sense.. How is the numnames related in any way to the length of the leftover-String?..

Answer (score 0):

With the change to make the loop condition `testname.length() > 0` the loop will never terminate if there isn't a space at the end of the name.

Consider the case in your first call when the string is `"Bobby"`:

```
int posBlank = testname.indexOf(' ');
```

There is no space, so `posBlank` is `-1`.

```
// cut off word
testname = testname.substring(posBlank + 1, testname.length());
```

The parameters to the substring call are `-1 + 1`, or `0`, and `5`.

The old string is `"Bobby"`, the new string is `"Bobby"`, and the loop will never terminate.